# Add leading zero to the hours in a date and time string

Tags: python, time, format

I have a variable `time = "12/13/2020 7:59"` and I would like to convert the string to `"12/13/2020 07:59"` (with leading zero before time-part).

I am not sure how to format it so that the hour has two digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enjoy using pandas `pd.to_datetime()` function to turn objects into proper datetime objects given it has the `infer_datetime_format` parameter which comes in handy and can also speed up the process too. Furthermore, with `strftime` you can then extract only the part you are interested in (or remove the seconds in this case):

```
time = '12/13/2020 7:59'
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime
pd.to_datetime(time,infer_datetime_format=True).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

Outputs:

```
13/12/2020 07:59
```

Comment: Thanks everybody. All ideas were great and solved my issue. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You could trust the [formatting options of `datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to do that for you:

```
from datetime import datetime

timestr = "12/13/2020 7:59"
    
dt = datetime.strptime(timestr, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
corrected = datetime.strftime(dt, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
    
print(corrected)
# 12/13/2020 07:59
```

As the doc states,

> When used with the strptime() method, the leading zero is optional for
> formats %d, %m, %H, %I, %M, [...].

So `strptime` accepts your text without the leading zeros, but `strftime` will format it properly when turning your datetime back into a string.